# C Double comparison in if statement not working as expected

Tags: c, gcc, double, comparison, precision

I am writing a program which takes an input from the user as a whole line, 
then parses the integers into an array and eventually calculates the average value and the value closest to the average.

I am running Windows 10, Dev C++ IDE and compiler TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit

I read that double comparison is an issue in C so I used the isless() function for more precision.
Still for some reason the comparison is not performed as it should.
This is my code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<float.h>

int main(){

char string[250];

//Prompt user to input sequence of integers
printf("Please enter the integer values: ");

//Read whole line from input
fgets (string, 250, stdin);


//Remove non-numeric characters from sequence and replace them with ' ' (space)
int j;
for(j=0; j<strlen(string); j++)
{
    if(!isdigit(string[j]))
    string[j] = ' ';
}

char *token;
char *rest = string;
int array[50]={0};
int i=0;


//Break string into Sub-tokens with ' ' as delimiter
// and parse them into an int array
while((token = strtok_r(rest, " ", &rest)))
{
    array[i]=atoi(token);
    i++;
}


double average,counter,sum;
i=0;
counter=0;
sum=0;

//Calculate the average
while(array[i]!=0)
{
    sum=sum+array[i];
    counter++;
    i++;

}
average=sum/counter;
//printf("Counter %lf",counter);
//printf("sum %lf", sum);
printf("Average : %lf\n",average);


int index=0;
i=0;
double difference;
while(array[i]!=0)
{
    if (i==0)
    {
        difference=fabs(fabs(array[0])-fabs(average));
    }

    if(isless((fabs(array[i])-fabs(average)),difference))
    {
        index=i;
    }


    printf("index %i difference %lf \n", index, fabs(fabs(array[i])-fabs(average)));
    printf("i value %i \n",i);
    i++;
}

printf("Closest element : %i\n", array[index]);


return 0;

}
```

Is there another way to compare the 2 values other than the isless function?
A test run of the program gives the following output:
[Test Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6rrv.png)

Please let me know if there exists another way to do the comparison in the last if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your logic..
You need to update the minimum difference whenever you update the index.

Try this:

```
if(isless((fabs(array[i])-fabs(average)),difference))
{
   index=i; 
   difference=fabs(fabs(array[i])-fabs(average));
}
```

Comment: You were right! I tried to update the difference and it now works as expected! Thank you for your help!